# Group.Key.Count() returns the same number for all groups

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have `Absence` database table.
I use `Entity Framework` to connect with database.

**Absence structure**

```
[ID]      INT           NOT NULL,
[STG]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[ABSDate] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL,
```

**Absence Data**

```
1   S-5 20/10/2020 14:00
2   S-3 25/10/2020 16:00
3   S-3 25/10/2020 14:00
4   S-7 26/10/2020 08:00
5   S-3 26/10/2020 10:00
6   S-3 26/10/2020 16:00
7   S-5 26/10/2020 16:00
8   S-2 28/10/2020 10:00
9   S-4 30/10/2020 14:00
10  S-7 01/11/2020 14:00
```

I want to fill a `chart` in a `winforms` project with some data. (`STG` and **Count of STG**)

**I tried**

```
        using (SchoolEntities context = new SchoolEntities())
        {
            var R = context.Absence.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(A => A.STG).Select(G => new { S = G.Key, ACount = G.Key.Count() });

            foreach (var item in R)
            {
                chart1.Series["Absences"].Points.AddXY(item.S, item.ACount);
            }
        }
```

**But I got data with same count (Every STG with same count)** as shown in the pic bellow

[image]

How can I get every `STG` with real count, cause as you will see in data stored in `Absence` table some `STG`'s have more or less than 3 records in `Absence`.

Massive thanks in advance.

Comment: `"S-4".Count()` is 3... same as for all other values of the Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```cs
var R = context.Absence.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(A => A.STG).Select(G => new { S = G.Key, ACount = G.Key.Count() });
```

to:

```cs
var R = context.Absence.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(A => A.STG).Select(G => new { S = G.Key, ACount = G.Count() });
```

Comment: Massive thanks sir, this help.